# How to get copy of an image in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an image and I want to drag that image, but when I drag that image I want the same image set on the same position where the original image is placed, and can also able to drag that image multiple times. This I am not able to do.

```
    <Image x:Name="im" ManipulationStarted="im_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="im_ManipulationCompleted" Height="100" Width="100" Source="/splash.png"  Margin="90,550,290,118">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="ImageTransformation" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="GestureListener_PinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" DragDelta="Image_DragDelta" />
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Please explain your problem better. Your question in very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the problem right, you are getting original image removed from source and placed into target control, but you want to copy it to target.
All you have to do is change `AllowedEffects` in code-behind drag-and-drop call to

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: i want to copy that image to its source which is defined in xaml